# Is it ok to use £ as delimiter in preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters, eregi

I am converting an eregi_replace function I found to preg_replace, but the eregi string has about every character on the keyboard in it. So I tried to use £ as the delimiter.. and it is working currently, but I wonder if it might potentially cause problems because it is a non-standard character?

Here is the eregi:

```
function makeLinks($text) {  
$text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
'<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
$text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
'\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);

    return $text;}
```

and the preg:

```
function makeLinks($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('£(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-^Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)£i',
    '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('£([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)£i',
    '\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);

        return $text;
}
```

Comment: What a sacrilegious use of this holy symbol! The Queen shall be hearing about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`£` is problematic because it isn't an ASCII character. It's from the Latin-1 charset and will only work if your PHP script also uses the 8bit representation. Should your file be encoded as UTF-8, then `£` will be represented as two bytes. And PCRE in PHP will trip over that. (At least my version does.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use parentheses to delimit a regex rather than a single character, for example:

```
preg_replace('(abc/def#ghi)i', ...);
```

That would probably be nicer than trying to find an obscure character that's not (yet) part of your expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the unicode character, just to be sure.

```
\u00A3
```

Watch out for the ereg functions and unicode support.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html
http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Long live the Queen.

Answer (score 2):

As @Chris pointed out, you can use paired bracket characters as delimiters, but they have to properly balanced throughout the regex.  For example, `'<<>'` won't work, but `'<<>>'` will.  You can use any of  `()`, `[]`, `{}` or `<>`, but I recommend the braces or the square brackets; parentheses are too common in regexes, and angle brackets are used in escape sequences like `(?>...)` (atomic group) and `(?<=...)` (lookbehind).

But I'm with @Brad on this one: why not just escape the delimiter character with a backslash whenever it appears in the regex?

Answer (score 1):

You would know the data being parsed better than we would. As far as regex is concerned, it's no different than any other ASCII value.

Though I have to ask: what's wrong with traditional then just escaping it? Or using a class with a character range?

Comment: I had escaping backwards originally (was trying to escape the delimiter instead of the occurrence of the delimiter in the expression... lol), but then i was more curious ove whether it would be a bad idea to use a character like that.